# Why is my dSLR sometimes not letting me take a photo?

Tags: canon, troubleshooting, shutter-release

I’ve just gotten a Canon 800D/T7i and I'm having issues using it. Sometimes when I try and take a photo it won’t let me. Can someone tell me why?
What’s the best mode to be taking photos in?

Comment: Can you please provide more information about what exposure and focus modes you are using when this occurs? What kind of subjects you are shooting? Is your subject static or moving? The more you tell us about when this occurs, the more likely we can help you. As your question stands now, there are at least half a dozen different things that could be contributing to your issue.

Comment: A quick way to test if it is inability to get focus-lock is to switch the lens to manual focus (as a test).  In that mode the camera should let you take the shot regardless of focus accuracy.

Answer (score 3):

Are you getting focus lock? Some cameras won't allow you to take a shot if focus isn't locked. This can happen if the subject is too close, it's moving, or trying to focus on an area lacking contrast. There are settings in the camera's control menus which will allow you to take a shot if focus isn't locked.

Comment: I find I can focus somewhat closer manually than the AF will with my Canon M6 Mark II, and it was the same on a 7D and 50D.  Turning off the AF can get the photo you want if you have the time for manual focus.